# Comments won't commit

Tags: bug, comments

Any ideas why I can no longer post comments?  I can type a comment, and the Add Comment button seems to submit, but the page then refreshes without my comment.

I've cleared my temp. Internet files (google suggestion) to no avail.  Browser is IE10 on Win 7 x64.

--- Update ---

I was just chuckling to myself.  I was about to respond to the comments below, using the Add Comment feature.  I feel like Homer Simpson.  Anyway, I carried on typing and pressed **Add Comment**, and guess what... comment lost.

Therefore, I can confirm it's not specific to a particular post.  No websense or other proxy in play...

Comment: I have this problem at work, because of a draconian websense proxy.

Comment: any particular question/answer you're having this problem on? Comments *seem* to be working OK so it might just be funky caching, or perhaps an overly "helpful" proxy like Tom suggests.

Comment: The I guess it's Fiddler time

Comment: I can tell you that IE 10 on Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8 x64 definitely do work. It must be an add-on, or something else in your environment that's causing this. Have you tried starting IE in no-add-ons mode?